# Crystal Report display data in a box

Tags: excel, crystal-reports

[image]

I need to display data in a crystal report in this format. I am new to crystal report I have no idea of doing this. Please help on this how can I draw these outer lines. The database is access

Answer (score 0):

In the menu, click insert and use either line or box or a combination of both to create outer lines for data. If using a cross-tab, report, use the format cross-tab for line properties.

[image]

There are numerous resources online to learn about CR.
Example: https://www.crystalreports.com/guides/#lp-pom-block-1322